# VSCode Extension API - listen for built-in context menu events

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building my first VSCode Extension and struggling a little bit.

Is it possible to listen to `context menu` events, like `copy` for example?

For example:
When user clicked on "Copy" in the context menu [(screenshot of context menu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n8lr.png)
I want to get the copied text.

There is an option to **add** commands to the `context menu`. But I don't want that, I want to listen to the existing built-in `copy` command.

I know, I can listen to the `keybinding`, but that doesn´t trigger the `context menu` event.

Comment: you can't hook on existing menu items, what do you want to do with the copied text

Comment: One way (maybe the only way) is to intercept those calls to the `copy` command by implementing your own `copy` command.  Then get the info you wanted, disable your command and send the arg to the buitin copy command.

Comment: who uses the `Copy` command from the context menu, Just use `Ctrl+C` and define a new  keybinding with your own command

Comment: @rioV8 i am building a [clipboard history extension](https://github.com/nkosakul/copy-cat). So onCopy, i want to store the text to the history.

Comment: @rioV8 i already listen to the keybinding ctrl+c. But i thought it would be user friendly to also listen to the context menu. There are some people who uses that instead of the shortcut

Comment: @Mark thanks for the suggestion! It might be a bit weard to have two copy commands in the context menu (default and mine) but i think there is no way around that.

Comment: I'll see if what I said is possible ;>}, I am doing something similar in an extension I wrote.  You would not have 2 `copy` commands in the menu, just the built-in one that you intercept.

Comment: you can also add a watcher to the clipboard content, just check every 0.5 sec to see if the clipboard has changed, be aware that you can't determine the multi cursor points in the clipboard content, so you can't restore the multi cursor content buffers.

Comment: what if people use the copy command in some command sequence for a multi-command keybinding

Comment: @Mark Can you get the function currently bound to `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction` and then define a new function for `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction` and call the original one, just make a decorator for `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction`

Comment: @rioV8 btw i tested your suggestion with the watcher, where i was watching the clipboard every 500ms. But that felt highly unperformant, or am i worrying to much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better version of my previous answer - it just gets the clipboard text in an easier method:

```js
let typeDisposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', async (arg) => myCopy(typeDisposable) );

async function myCopy(typeDisposable)  {

    typeDisposable.dispose();      // must dispose to avoid endless loops

    // run the built-in copy command
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction');

    // get the copied text
    const clipboardText = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText();
    // use your clipboard text here
    console.log(clipboardText);

    // re-register to continue intercepting copy commands
    typeDisposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', async (arg) => myCopy(typeDisposable) );
    context.subscriptions.push(typeDisposable);
}

context.subscriptions.push(typeDisposable);
```

---

- [Previous version of answer]

This seems to work - but should be thoroughly tested (it is sort of a thought experiment at this point):

```js
let typeDisposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', async (arg) => myCopy(typeDisposable) );

async function myCopy(typeDisposable)  {

    typeDisposable.dispose();

    // get the selectedText from the editor here
    const selectedRange = new vscode.Range(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.start, vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.end);
    const copiedText = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText(selectedRange);
    // use your copiedText here

    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction');
    typeDisposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', async (arg) => myCopy(typeDisposable) );
    context.subscriptions.push(typeDisposable);
}

context.subscriptions.push(typeDisposable);
```

You would have to modify this for multiple selections which should be pretty easy.

This will intercept **ALL** calls to `copy`, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.   Maybe you are able to limit registering the command to a more limited set of circumstances?

Comment: are the commands, like keybindings, handled in a stack way or is the command name just a key in a function dictionary. If it is a stack than the processing would result in a full-list scan, or is it a stack per dictionary entry, not likely they have implemented the command override

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I tried that out locally and it worked.
Im gonna test it update this here, if i found downsides

Comment: I updated the answer a little to be cleaner and slightly simpler.